# Check out Attribute on WooCommerce

Tags: plugins

I am using WooCommerce on one of the site. I need to add one more field at the time of checkout to ask buyer wheteher to issue Invoice on his name or the name of his business?

Any advise how to do that? Or something like this is already there in Woo Commerce? Or what could be the simplest way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it happens, I just blogged about this yesterday, for how to [add a subscribe to mailing list checkbox](http://snippets.webaware.com.au/snippets/subscribe-to-mailing-list-in-woocommerce-checkout/). The key points are:

- look at the [WooCommerce tutorial](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters)
- woocommerce_checkout_fields is a filter hook that allows you to add or modify what fields appear on the checkout form
- woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta is an action hook that allows you to save your new fields
- woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys is a filter hook that allows you to add your new fields to the confirmation emails
- the name you pick to save the post meta will be its label in the email

Here's the code I used:

```
class WooSubscribeCheckbox {

    // add hooks into WooCommerce
    public static function run() {
        add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields',
            array(__CLASS__, 'filterWooCheckoutFields'));

        add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta',
            array(__CLASS__, 'actionWooCheckoutUpdateOrderMeta'));

        add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys',
            array(__CLASS__, 'filterWooEmailOrderMetaKeys'));
    }

    /**
    * add custom fields to WooCommerce checkout
    * @param array fields
    * @return array
    */
    public static function filterWooCheckoutFields($fields) {
        global $woocommerce;

        // add field at end of billing fields section
        $fields['billing']['our_mailing_subscribe'] = array(
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'label' => 'Subscribe to mailing list?',
            'placeholder' => 'Subscribe to mailing list',
            'required' => false,
            'class' => array(),
            'label_class' => array(),
        );

        return $fields;
    }

    /**
    * save custom order fields
    * @param int $order_id
    */
    public static function actionWooCheckoutUpdateOrderMeta($order_id) {
        if (isset($_POST['our_mailing_subscribe'])) {
            update_post_meta($order_id, 'Subscribe to mailing list',
                stripslashes($_POST['our_mailing_subscribe']));
        }
    }

    /**
    * add our custom fields to WooCommerce order emails
    * @param array $keys
    * @return array
    */
    public static function filterWooEmailOrderMetaKeys($keys) {
        $keys[] = 'Subscribe to mailing list';

        return $keys;
    }

}

WooSubscribeCheckbox::run();
```

Comment: +1 much better than a RTFM, but you already had it coded ;) - thx for aussieSing clarification!

Comment: Thanks, and Happy New Year -- it's already over 10 hours old here, feels hotter. I hope it's going well for you! cheers, Ross

Comment: Thanks, Ross, happy NY too! Snow haven't arrived here yet, greetings from Spain, Rodolfo

Comment: Thanks, this helped me to do what I needed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin is packed with hooks and provides an [extensive documentation](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/).

From that link: [Tutorial – Customising checkout fields using hooks and filters](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/snippets/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-hooks-and-filters/).

> #### How are checkout fields loaded into WooCommerce?
>
> The fields for the checkout (billing and shipping) come from the countries class (`class-wc-countries.php`) and the `get_address_fields` function- this is so locale settings are applied to the fields letting WooCommerce enable/disable fields based on the users location.
>
> Before returning the fields, WC will run the fields through a filter. This allows them to be edited by third party plugins and themes ***(and your own custom code)***.

<sup>*my emphasis*</sup>

Comment: Pity that we cannot edit those docs... It is "CustomiZing" and it should be "using actions and filters", or only "using hooks". (just tweeted the author about this)

Comment: CustomiSing is how we say it Down Under, I think at least one of those guys is either Aussie or Kiwi.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to code it yourself. There is a nice plugin available here:
http://terrytsang.com/shop/shop/woocommerce-custom-checkout-options/

Comment: [An answer should be more than just a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion). Please add a solution.