# Change Label for field used in Woo Commerce

Tags: plugins

I'm using WooCommerce, and using a BACS Payment method which is actually Bank Trasnfer. The fields account details are fine, but for Indian context.. i need to change following two fields labels to something else. For example:

Change IBAN label to MICR Code, and
BIC to IFSC.

And also need to disable Sort Code.

However, please note that I don't to make chanegs into plugin's code itself. So looking for some function that can help change the label from my theme function file.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the [documentation](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com) has nothing about this? The answer to your other [similar Question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/77781/12615) was a "Google this for me" solution...

Comment: Yes, after posting it here.. I find a way to implement it in Woo Commerce codex. But earlier I was unable to find that, hence posted it here. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It gets its label using a localisation call, `__('IBAN', 'woocommerce')`, so you could always just intercept that and change the text:

```
/**
* filter translations, to replace some WooCommerce text with our own
* @param string $translation the translated text
* @param string $text the text before translation
* @param string $domain the gettext domain for translation
* @return string
*/
function wpse_77783_woo_bacs_ibn($translation, $text, $domain) {
    if ($domain == 'woocommerce') {
        switch ($text) {
            case 'IBAN':
                $translation = 'MICR';
                break;

            case 'BIC':
                $translation = 'IFSC';
                break;
        }
    }

    return $translation;
}

add_filter('gettext', 'wpse_77783_woo_bacs_ibn', 10, 3);
```

Comment: hey, thanks. I was sure there must be a way for this.. but I was unable to figure out it my self. How did you find it? May be next time I can figure out it myself.

Comment: I went to the best documentation there is: the source code. Documentation often lies or is deficient, but the source code rarely lies. In this instance, I looked in the code for that payment gateway module: `woocommerce/classes/gateways/bacs/class-wc-bacs.php`

Comment: Thanks. This also works if you are trying to get it to show Australian bank information which is represented as BSB and Account Number.